# How to enable PUT and DELETE on Apache2 and PHP7 with Slim

Tags: php, apache, http

I have been struggling to enable `PUT` and `DELETE` requests from my API server. I checked the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf` file and it looked like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root

        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
                AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Require all granted
                </Limit>
                <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Require all denied
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I added `PUT` and `DELETE` after `OPTIONS` in both `limit` and `limitExcept` blocks and restarted the apache server. Still, my `PUT`/`DELETE` calls send me the following error:

```
Method not allowed
Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET, POST
```

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks!